# can we use plus sign in argument while calling number() function is xslt

Tags: xslt

in older version number(+10) returned 10
but in currect version number(+10) returns NaN
could you please clarify, is it correct according to xslt v1.0 or 2.0 standarts?

Comment: I think you have it backwards. `number(+10)` generates an error in XSLT 1.0. That conforms to the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Number-Functions. XSLT 2.0 follows a different rule: https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#casting-to-double

Answer (score 2):

A unary plus sign is allowed by XPath 2.0 and later, but not by XPath 1.0.

However, I think that (in 1.0) `number(+10)` should give you a syntax error, whereas `number('+10')` should give you NaN.

The XPath 2.0 spec explicitly lists this in its appendix detailing incompatibilities:

> When converting strings to numbers (either explicitly when using the
> number function, or implicitly say on a function call), certain
> strings that converted to the special value NaN under XPath 1.0 will
> convert to values other than NaN under XPath 2.0. These include any
> number written with a leading + sign, any number in exponential
> floating point notation (for example 1.0e+9), and the strings INF and
> -INF.